Question about creating addition tables after dividing natural numbers from 1 to 2n into two sets of n elements each.
Recently, I attempted to divide the numbers from $1$ to $2n$ into two specific sets of $n$ numbers each and create an addition table using elements from the two sets (i.e., only summing elements from one set with elements from the other set) with the sums taken modulo $2n+1$, such that each number from $1$ to $2n$ appears exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ times in the table(so, n must be an even number). However, I discovered that such a balanced appearance of numbers in the addition table is only possible for specific values of $n$. What form must $n$ take for there to exist a method to successfully achieve the above attempt?
As a supporting basis for the above question, the following code was used:
import itertools
from collections import Counter

n = 4
m1 = 2 * n + 1
m2 = (n * n) // (n * 2)

numbers = list(range(1, m1))

# Function to check if the sets satisfy the condition
def check_sets(set_a, set_b):
    addition_results = [(a + b) % m1 for a in set_a for b in set_b]
    counter = Counter(addition_results)
    return all(counter[i] == m2 for i in range(1, m1))

# Try all possible combinations
result = None
for set_a in itertools.combinations(numbers, n):
    set_b = [x for x in numbers if x not in set_a]
    if check_sets(set_a, set_b):
        result = {
            "Set1": set(set_a),
            "Set2": set(set_b)
        }
        break

if result:
    print(f"Set1: {result['Set1']}")
    print(f"Set2: {result['Set2']}")
else:
    print("No valid partition found")



According to this code, for $n$= $2$, $6$, and $8$, there exist partitioning methods that satisfy the above conditions. (However, for $n$=$4$, $10$ there are no partitioning methods.)
The methods are as follows:
For n=2, mod 5:
{1, 4}{2, 3}



(+)
2
3




1
3
4


4
1
2



For n=6, mod 13:
{1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12}{2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11}



(+)
2
5
6
7
8
11




1
3
6
7
8
9
12


3
5
8
9
10
11
1


4
6
9
10
11
12
2


9
11
1
2
3
4
7


10
12
2
3
4
5
8


12
1
4
5
6
7
10



For n=8, mod 17:
{1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16}{3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 14}



(+)
3
5
6
7
10
11
12
14




1
4
6
7
8
11
12
13
15


2
5
7
8
9
12
13
14
16


4
7
9
10
11
14
15
16
1


8
11
13
14
15
1
2
3
5


9
12
14
15
16
2
3
4
6


13
16
1
2
3
6
7
8
10


15
1
3
4
5
8
9
10
12


16
2
4
5
6
9
10
11
13




Just to be clear, are you talking about addition modulo the Fermat numbers $F_j=2^{2^j}+1$ where only the first few are known to be prime (i.e. ${3,5,17,257,65537}$)? Also, its a little confusing you start off talking about arbitrarily dividing the numbers into two sets, but then seem to imply only a subset of arbitrary partitions work. One necessary condition is if a number is in set $a$, its additive inverse $\bmod m_1$ must not be in set $b$ where $m_1=2 n+1$.

I apologize for not explaining the problem clearly as I was writing the question in a hurry yesterday. I have revised my text, so I would appreciate it if you could read it again when you have the chance.

The two sets that you are getting are the set of quadratic residues modulo $2n+1$ and the set of quadratic nonresidues modulo $2n+1$. This will work for any prime value of $2n+1$ (in your examples, $5$, $13$, and $17$). See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue For $n=14$, you'll get ${1,4,5,6,7,9,13,16,20,22,23,24,25,28}$ and its complement.

@GerryMyerson So the two partitions exist $\bmod m$ where $m=2 n+1$ if-and-only-if $m\in\mathbb{P}$? In other words, its impossible to find two partitions satisfying the condition $\bmod m$ if $m\notin\mathbb{P}$?

I don't know. One problem is that if $2n+1$ isn't prime, then there are numbers $k$, $1\le k\le2n$, such that $\gcd(k,2n+1)>1$, and that has an effect on the sums. I tried doing something for $m=21=3\times7$ by leaving out the multiples of three and seven, so just using the $12$ numbers, ${1,2,4,5,8,10,11,13,16,17,19,20}$. I tried $A={1,4,10,13,16,19}$, $B={2,5,8,11,17,20}$ and found each of ${3,6,9,12,15,18}$ came up five times, and zero came up six times. I tried $A={1,2,4,8,11,16}$, $B={5,10,13,17,19,20}$ and found zero came up six times, multiples of seven each came up thrice..

(continued), multiples of three came up twice each, and the other $12$ numbers came up once each.
